# нужно сделать систему баллов в js

Tags: javascript

я не могу сделать систему баллов в js нужна помощь, я недавно начал изучать язык, и поэтому в коде много ошибок. идея - загадывается рандомное число и я его должен угадать, если угадаю то добавляется 1 балл, и так далее. у меня получается добавлять 1 балл, а дальше код не работает.

```js
function checkForm(el) {

  stavka = document.getElementById('stavka').value;
  randNum = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

  const input = document.getElementById('www')
  const p = document.getElementById('point')

  console.log('мое число: ' + randNum)
  console.log('твое число: ' + stavka)

// вот строчки которые нужно доделать \/
  point = 0

  if(stavka == randNum) {
    point++
    console.log(point)      
    p.innerHTML = point
  }
// вот строчки которые нужно доделать /\

  if(stavka == randNum) {
    console.log('win')
    input.innerHTML = 'win'
  }
  
  if(stavka > randNum) {
    console.log('твое число больше')
    input.innerHTML = 'твое число больше - losses'
    
  }

  if(stavka < randNum) {
    console.log('твое число меньше')
    input.innerHTML = 'твое число меньше - losses'
    
  }
  
  if(stavka >= 11) {
    console.log('менчик ввыоди правильно!')
    input.innerHTML = 'менчик ввыоди правильно! - dayn'
    
  }

  return false;
  
}
```

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper3{
    width: 940px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.panel_pq{
    float: left;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.stavka{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.stavka{
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>casino</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wapper3">
        <div class="panel_pq">
            <div class="panel_panel_pq">
                <a href="">zxc</a><br><br><br><br><br>
                <a href="">zxc</a><br><br><br><br><br>
                <a href="/qwe.html">zxc</a><br><br><br><br><br>
                <a href="/index.html">home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form id="1" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" method="post">
                <h4 style="color: antiquewhite;">введи цифру от 1 до 10 <br><br><br> alfa-version</h4>
                <input type="text" placeholder="сумма" id="stavka" class="stavka">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Готово" class="stavka_2">
                <p id="www" style="color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.863);">результат</p>
                <p id="point" style="color: antiquewhite;">0</p>
                <!-- <a href="/money.html"><h3 style="color: antiquewhite;">напоминаю! сюда кидать деньги</h3></a> -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://bluecoc.online/phonk.html - вот сайт если нужен

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Выдает ошибку или что-то другое?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: ошибку не выдает,  я не могу понять почему после 1 правильного ответа балл зачисляется, а после нет

Comment: Уберите переменную point и увеличивайте значение переменной p вот так `p.innerHTML = Number(p.innerTEXT)+1`. Вы point`ом каждый раз зануляете значение

Comment: ` if(stavka == randNum) {
    console.log(point)      
    p.innerHTML = Number(p.innerTEXT)+1
  }  ` вот так сделал и пишет ошибку NaN , может я то-то сделал не то?

Comment: Я там ошибся, нужно `p.innerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вот моё решение интегрированное в Ваш код:**

```js
function checkForm(el) {

  stavka = document.getElementById('stavka').value;
  randNum = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

  const input = document.getElementById('www')
  const p = document.getElementById('point')

  console.log('мое число: ' + randNum)
  console.log('твое число: ' + stavka)

// вот строчки которые нужно доделать \/
  

  if(stavka == randNum) {
    var tekushieBalli = parseFloat(document.getElementById('point').value); 
      var shag = 1;
    tekushieBalli = tekushieBalli+shag;
    

    document.getElementById('point').value = tekushieBalli;
    console.log(point)      
    
  }
// вот строчки которые нужно доделать /\

  if(stavka == randNum) {
    console.log('win')
    input.innerHTML = 'win'
  }
  
  if(stavka > randNum) {
    console.log('твое число больше')
    input.innerHTML = 'твое число больше - losses'
    
  }

  if(stavka < randNum) {
    console.log('твое число меньше')
    input.innerHTML = 'твое число меньше - losses'
    
  }
  
  if(stavka >= 11) {
    console.log('менчик ввыоди правильно!')
    input.innerHTML = 'менчик ввыоди правильно! - dayn'
    
  }

  return false;
  
}
```

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper3{
    width: 940px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.panel_pq{
    float: left;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.stavka{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.stavka{
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>casino</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wapper3">
        <div class="panel_pq">
            <div class="panel_panel_pq">
                <a href="">zxc</a><br><br><br><br><br>
                <a href="">zxc</a><br><br><br><br><br>
                <a href="/qwe.html">zxc</a><br><br><br><br><br>
                <a href="/index.html">home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form id="1" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" method="post">
                <h4 style="color: antiquewhite;">введи цифру от 1 до 10 <br><br><br> alfa-version</h4>
                <input type="text" placeholder="сумма" id="stavka" class="stavka">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Готово" class="stavka_2">
                <p id="www" style="color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.863);">результат</p>
                <textarea id="point" style="background-color: #2e2e2e; width:20px; height:20px; outline:transparent; border:transparent; resize: none; color:antiquewhite;" readonly>0</textarea>
                <!-- <a href="/money.html"><h3 style="color: antiquewhite;">напоминаю! сюда кидать деньги</h3></a> -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Способ через **`<textarea>`**:

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Баллы:</p><textarea id="balli" style="width:20px; height:20px; outline:transparent; border:transparent; resize: none;" readonly>0</textarea> 
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="SlojenieBallov()">

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = reset;

     function reset() {


     document.getElementById('balli').value = 0;
        
    }

    function SlojenieBallov() {
    var tekushieBalli = parseFloat(document.getElementById('balli').value); 
    var shag = 1;
    tekushieBalli = tekushieBalli+shag;
    

    document.getElementById('balli').value = tekushieBalli;    
    
   }
    
    

</script>

</body>
</html
```

Сможете данный счётчик прикрутить к вашей функции? Подходит ли Вам такое решение?

Comment: так как я новичок, мне это особо ничего не дает, что мне именно нужно поменять? простите если много прошу

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ответ обновил, если и так сложно, то могу попробовать написать код за Вас, ибо я тоже новичок и жажду практики.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).